# Do you have any idea why my contributions using gitKraken won't show up on my gitHub account?

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

so I'm logged in to gitKraken using my github account.

I have 2 email addresses associated to my github account and I'm connected to gitKraken using my github account (using eventually my primary email address).

I've just discovered recently that my contributions using gitKraken didn't show up neither in the github projects nor in my github profile. It's like a non-existent user as you can see in this picture showing the network graph of one of the projects: [network graph showing non-existent user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWy4.png)

I'm working with 2 friends and I'm not even being recognized as a contributor: [contributors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZMtu.png) which is weird since I was invited and I can see in my profile that I'm a contributor [repositories tab in profile settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvyMc.png)

Even when I commit from gitKraken It's displayed as I'm not the same guy when I tested it doing a commit using the command line then doing another one using gitKraken as shown here: [different profiles shown in gitKraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLNK9.png)

I'm really confused on how is this even possible? since my gitKraken account is linked to my github account and I'm using the same email address.

Comment: The most basic question would be: `did you set up user.name and user.email correctly?`. That is what will be used when a new revision is created.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks for answering, yeah I did that, I found out that my global `user.name and user.email` were not the same as my email and username on gitkraken (but the email used is linked to the same github account). So I logged in on gitkraken using this time the other email and username  (which usually show up in contributions when I commit with these values) and I tested one commit with these values but as usual the commit didn't show up in my contributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, turns out I used another email for a project, that's why it didn't show up in my contributions.
As soon as I added that email to my github account, everything showed up as expected.

Comment: I've got the same email on GitHub, GitKraken and in gitconfig but it still doesn't show my profile on commits (uses autogenerated avatar) and I've noticed those commits are not shown on my profile as contribution :(